# In letzter Minute - grammatic question

Tags: grammaticality, adjective-ending, declension-table

In phrase "In letzter Minute"

Why letzt-ER not letzt-EN?

If "in" präposition introduces Dativ, and letzt. is an adjective,
than  according to adj. declenation, correct form should be "letzten". Can someone explain this to me?

Thanks,
Jerzy

Comment: Please show what the declension table say about "letzten". Is it weak or strong declination? Is it singular or plural?

Answer (score 6):

A look in our favourite [declension table](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/letzter#Declension) reveals, you are mistaken.

> in letzter Minute

Because *Minute* is female, it has to be *letzter* in Dativ. That is because there is no article in this expression. However, you would be correct for

> in **der** letzten Minute

This time, there is an article present. This is known as strong and weak declension.